# Reference firebase post by key, pushes to "undefined"

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

### **What I am trying to do.**

I am making an app that has posts and comments using react native and firebase. I am trying to add comments to it. I am trying to make it so that when you tap on a post, it takes you to another tab with the post, then the user can use a text input box to push a comment to firebase.

### **Problem**

When the user pushes the text to firebase, instead of pushing to the post, it pushes to "undefined". Here is my code when the user presses the upload button:

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/'+params.key).push().set({ comment:this.state.commentInput });
```

"Comment input" being what is pushed, and "params.key" being the key of the post (I tested this and it is the correct key). I would love some help getting the comments to push to the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is for you to validate the input before pushing it into firebase

```
 if (params.key === undefined && this.state.commentInput === undefined) {
     console.log('Wrong user input')
 } else {
    firebase.database().ref('posts').child(params.key).push().set({ comment:this.state.commentInput }).then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('success push new value')
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('any error: ', err);
    });
 }
```

Comment: when I go onto firebase though, under undefined is a random key and the input of the comment.

Comment: That's mean params.key is undefined. I recommend to use child. Let me edit my answer

Comment: I did some testing, and whenever I test the exact code you gave me, the app refreshes and doesn't upload anything. Weirdly though when I manually input a key and some random content (as a string) it works completely fine. I think since the app is randomly reloading it's getting caught on something and just reloads the whole app.

Comment: Can you try again. I updated the code above so that it just check undefined property value.

Comment: I tried the new code, and that gave me an error. I tried rendering the key along .with the post to make sure that the key was working, then I tried making a button that would refresh the key. The button that refreshed the key didn't solve the problem, it just kept everything the same. I tried manually adding the key as a string to the code, and that worked. When I used "String(params.key)" in my code, it kept pushing to undefined in firebase, despite having the right key. Did I not turn it into a string the right way? Am I doing the totally wrong thing here?

Comment: params.key should be string, if not you need to cast it into string using toString() for eg: params.key.toString(). Well, try to hook catch function at the end of query method to see what's is an error print on the console. You can refer my updated answer above

Comment: I tried using toString(), and that kept automatically reloading the app. I tried using the code you gave me, and that didn't give me any errors or anything, it just also reloaded the app when I tried pushing. I tested the key one more time, and it is the exact key I want, so I really don't know why it would be refreshing.

Comment: I was messing around, and I actually found a way to get it to work. Your original answer was basically right!